# Why is it that I "cannot use assignment expressions with comparison" in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, operators, python-assignment-expression

### In the examples below `x` is assigned using the walrus operator and is then printed.

```
mystring = "hello, world"


#if 1
if x := mystring == "hello, world":
    print(x)

#if 2
if x := (mystring == "hello, world"):
    print(x)

#if 3
if (x := mystring) == "hello, world":
    print(x)

#if 4
if "hello, world" in (x := mystring):
    print(x)
```

The Output:

```
True
True
hello, world
hello, world
```

### I *believe* that I understand how each of these if statements works...

verbosely:

1. `#if 1` and `#if 2` are the same thing where the string comparison `==` returns `True`, and that value is reassigned to `x`.
2. `#if 3` assigns `mystring` as `x` before checking the truth of this equal to `"hello, world"`.
3. `#if 4`assigns `mystring` as `x` then checks if `"hello, world"` is in this string.

### So

**What** about this final `#if 5` is ambiguous to Python such that it gives a Syntax Error?

```
#if 5
if "hello, world" in x := mystring:
    print(x)
```

```
SyntaxError: cannot use assignment expressions with comparison
```

Is this related to PEP 572 [Exceptional Cases](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases):

> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level of an expression statement.

> there is no syntactic position where both are valid.

In reality I am looping through the pathlib Path.iterdir() generator object that yields strings with `.stem`. This does not change the result:

```
for file in folder.iterdir():
    x := file.stem == "mystring":
        print(x)
```

Comment: The `in` operator has higher priority than the `:=` operator. What do you expect to happen to `if ('hello world' in x) := mystring`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` and other comparison operators have a higher precedence than `:=`. So when you write

```
if "hello, world" in x := mystring:
```

it means:

```
if ("hello, world" in x) := mystring:
```

which is invalid as it tries to assign to `"hello, world" in x`. To get it you work you need to use parentheses:

```
if "hello, world" in (x := mystring):
```

Comment: Obvious now you say it that statements including operators with words like 'in' are in a precedence hierarchy. I'd just assumed symbols over everything first?